# GCC confuses `set` member function with `std::set`

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-bug

The following C++ code gives an error with GCC (e.g. 13.1, see [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/YY7EYWoK6)) where the compiler seems to confuse the `set` member function template with `std::set`:

```cpp
#include <set>
using namespace std;
template <typename T> struct C {
    template <int S> void set(T const &) { }
};
template <typename T> struct D : C<T> {
    void f(T const & v) { this->template set<0>(v); }
};
```

It has obviously something to do with the `using namespace std;` line but I don't understand how the compiler can try to lookup `set` in the global or `std` namespace when it is explicitly qualified by `this->`.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Interesting. Only appears in GCC. Clang and MSVC accept it. Smells like a compiler bug.

Comment: Correction: only appears in GCC 11.4 - trunk. GCC 11.3 and older accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GCC bug report about this [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106310).

According to the comments there is a relevant C++ standard defect report regarding the behavior, but I couldn't find it.

For a bit of context:

When you have a class member access expression like `X->Y` (assuming no `operator->` overload), lookup for `Y` is done first in the context of the class type of `X`.

But if that doesn't succeed, then lookup for `Y` is also done in the scope of the expression. This would e.g. find `std::set` if `Y` is `set` and you have a `using namespace std;` in scope (`template` doesn't affect the lookup). Because your base class `C<T>` is dependent its member `set` won't be found in the first lookup phase from the template definition context.

This lookup rule allows you to write e.g. `this->set<int>::size()` if the current class is derived from `set<int>`.

The question now is how this is supposed to interact with the current class having a dependent base that could cause lookup for `set` to find its member instead in the instantiation context.

I haven't looked up what the current and previous standards say about this exactly.

Comment: Oh, a comment in the linked bug report from some minutes ago says it would have been fixed for v14.  Nice!

Comment: @imix I am still wondering though whether this is conforming with what the standard says at the moment. I'll have a look later...